# Is there a way to run execvp() several times without recursion in C?

Tags: c, linux

I'm currently trying to build something similar to the `|` in linux and it should be able to take n amount of arguments as long as they are piped together. I execute these arguments (like `ls`, `sort`, etc) using `execvp()` by passing it the argument and then the array that holds the argument and its options.

HOWEVER, the proplem lies in that `execvp()` does not return anything.. so when i `fork()` and go into the child process, it does what it needs to do, `execvp()` then goes into the parent process. Now i can recursively fork again and keep on going to get as many child processes as needed and call n amounts of `execvp()` but I would like to know if there is ITERATIVE way of doing the same thing.

Hope I was clear enough, it's very late, so sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: The answer in that question uses an iterative method.

Comment: I'll check that out now, thanks for pointing it out! Damn it, Barmar... I think you may have just saved my life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `wait(&status)` on each fork.  Here is an example that uses argv as a list of file descriptors to open in forks and then wait for them all to finish.  For exec* functions it will wait for an exit.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    unsigned int i,fd,*status;
    for(i=1;i<argc;++i){
        if(fork()==0){
            fd = open(argv[i], 04000);
            if (fd<2) return 2;
            //do stuff with fd
            close(fd);
            //do stuff with data
            return 0;
        }
    }
    while(i--){
        wait(&status);
        //do stuff with status
    }
    return 0;
}
```